# PHP add array to an object

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to query the database to:

1. Get a football match record
2. Get all the players that are part of that match

There are three tables: `Matches` | `Players` | `Match_Players`

`Match_Players` simply connects the two other tables together.

I am trying to return the result in JSON.

The problem is with the second query. It returns an `Errant Query`. This is what I have so far:

```
$matches = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($matchResult)) 
{
    while($match = mysql_fetch_assoc($matchResult)) 
    {
        $players_query = 
            "SELECT p.* FROM match_players mp 
            LEFT JOIN players p on p.id = mp.player_id
            WHERE mp.id = ".$match->player_id; // <--- This is the error

        $playersResult = mysql_query($players_query,$link) or die('Errant query: '.$players_query);
        $players       = array();

        if(mysql_num_rows($playersResult)) 
        {
            while($player = mysql_fetch_assoc($playersResult)) 
            {
                $players[] = $player;
            }
        }

        $match->$players = $players;    
        $matches[] = $match;
    }
}
```

**Update**

I have changed the second SQL statement by replacing `$match->player_id` to `$match['player_id'];`. **However**, I am not receiving the collection of players. All I can see is the match details. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$match['player_id']
```

(array syntax) not

```
$match->player_id
```

(object syntax) or use

```
mysql_fetch_object
```

Though i expect you should do one query, not a loop

Comment: Please check the update. Though the error has gone, I can't see a returned result of the players.

Comment: @Subby same problem, change `$match->$players = $players;` to `$match['players'] = $players;`

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the query be like this?

```
"SELECT p.* 
FROM match_players mp 
RIGHT JOIN players p on p.id = mp.player_id
WHERE mp.match_id = ".$match->id;
```

or like this

```
"SELECT p.*
FROM players p, match_players mp, matches m
WHERE p.id = mp.player_id AND mp.match_id = m.id
AND m.id = ". $match->id;
```

created an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f88f5/2/0) to try and check the queries and they are fine...

Comment: I just noticed that too JUST before you posted :) I still don't see the players coming through. If I run this code through PHPMYAdmin, the results come through A-OK.

Comment: It throws an errant query when I paste your update in.

Comment: Ah, you made a left join which will give you only match_players stuff back... you need to do a right join

Comment: Errant query: SELECT p.* FROM match_players mp RIGHT JOIN players p on p.id = mp.player_id WHERE mp.match_id =

Comment: this is probably a stupid question but you are putting an id after the = ? :P e.g. `"SELECT p.* FROM match_players mp RIGHT JOIN players p on p.id = mp.player_id WHERE mp.match_id = 1"`

Comment: That query works fine in PHPMyAdmin but it's not in the PHP file. Maybe it's not pulling the $match->id out?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51783/discussion-between-subby-and-furier)